# DAX - Split row values into new column based of date values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with some task data, and these tasks has resources and a start & finish date.

Table example

```
Task    Month/Year    Resources
A-1       01.2019        5
A-1       02.2019        5
A-1       03.2019        5
A-1       04.2019        5
A-1       05.2019        5
A-1       06.2019        5
A-1       07.2019        5
A-1       08.2019        5
A-1       09.2019        5
A-1       10.2019        5
A-1       11.2019        5
A-1       12.2019        5
```

My problem is if `A-1` has a start date of 02.2019 finish date of 10.2019 and would therefore like to sum the Resource column and split it over the period 01.2019 to 09.2019. So it would look like this:

```
Task    Month/Year    Resources     CalculatedColumn
    A-1       01.2019        5             
    A-1       02.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       03.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       04.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       05.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       06.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       07.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       08.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       09.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       10.2019        5             6,66
    A-1       11.2019        5             
    A-1       12.2019        5
```

I can get the start and end date by lookupvalue. But I'm lost on how I'd do the actual calculation.

```
CalculatedColumn = 
VAR StartDate = LOOKUPVALUE(...)
VAR EndDate = LOOKUPVALUE(...)

VAR Results = CALCULATE(...)

RETURN Results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to get the start and end dates, the rest might look like this:

```
CalculatedColumn = 
VAR StartDate = DATE(2019,2,1)
VAR EndDate = DATE(2019,10,1)
VAR Dates = DATESBETWEEN(Table3[Date], StartDate, EndDate)
RETURN
IF([Date] IN Dates,
    DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Table3[Resources]),
            FILTER(Table3, Table3[Task] = EARLIER(Table3[Task]))
        ),
        COUNTROWS(Dates)
    )
)
```